# « Ma sœur est de sept ans moins âgée que moi. »

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, ordre-des-mots, comparatifs

Quelqu'un pourrait-il me dire si cette phrase est correcte :

> Ma sœur est de sept ans moins âgée que moi.

Je ne sais pas s'il faut employer « de » ou non...
Merci d'avance.

Comment: c'est très soutenu comme langage, le plus utilisé serait *Ma soeur a 7 ans de moins que moi*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour exprimer cette idée, j'emploierais:

> Ma soeur est sept ans moins agée que moi

La réponse fournie par LPH me paraît plus "formelle"

> Ma soeur est moins agée que moi de sept ans

On pourrait aussi transformer le "moins agée" en "plus jeune :

> Ma soeur est sept ans plus jeune que moi

Cette version est disons plus positive dans la mesure où l'on se présente comme jeune, et sa soeur "plus jeune" au contraire de "moins agée" où l'on se présente "agé", qui est un euphémisme courant pour "vieux".

On pourrait aussi employer le terme "cadet(te)" :

> Ma soeur est ma cadette de sept ans

Finalement, notons que l'autre réponse proposée par LPH me paraît également la plus naturelle, mais aussi la plus neutre :

> Ma soeur a sept ans de moins que moi

Comment: Je me demande si *est sept ans moins agée que moi* n'est pas un peu un belgicisme.

Answer (score 2):

Il semble que l'ordre ne soit pas le plus habituel et qu'il faudrait plutôt dire et écrire

- « Ma sœur est moins âgée que moi de sept ans. ». ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=que+moi+de+*+ans&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cque%20moi%20de%20%2A%20ans%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bque%20moi%20de%20deux%20ans%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bque%20moi%20de%20trois%20ans%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bque%20moi%20de%20sept%20ans%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bque%20moi%20de%20quatre%20ans%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bque%20moi%20de%20dix%20ans%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bque%20moi%20de%20vingt%20ans%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bque%20moi%20de%20cinq%20ans%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bque%20moi%20de%20six%20ans%3B%2Cc0))

On ne trouve pas « [est de * ans moins](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=est+de+*+ans+moins&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) »

Il semble que les combinaisons [est * ans moins âgée,est * ans moins âgé,est * ans moins agée,est * ans moins agée](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=est+*+ans+moins+%C3%A2g%C3%A9e%2Cest+*+ans+moins+%C3%A2g%C3%A9%2Cest+*+ans+moins+ag%C3%A9e%2Cest+*+ans+moins+ag%C3%A9e&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=), quoique  elles puisse me sembler naturelles, ne sont pas utilisées, alors que celles du type « [a * ans de moins](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+*+ans+de+moins&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ca%20%2A%20ans%20de%20moins%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20deux%20ans%20de%20moins%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20dix%20ans%20de%20moins%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20vingt%20ans%20de%20moins%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20trois%20ans%20de%20moins%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20quatre%20ans%20de%20moins%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20trente%20ans%20de%20moins%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20cinq%20ans%20de%20moins%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20quinze%20ans%20de%20moins%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20huit%20ans%20de%20moins%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20six%20ans%20de%20moins%3B%2Cc0) » et « [a * ans de plus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+*+ans+de+plus&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ca%20%2A%20ans%20de%20plus%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20dix%20ans%20de%20plus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20vingt%20ans%20de%20plus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20deux%20ans%20de%20plus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20quatre%20ans%20de%20plus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20trois%20ans%20de%20plus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20cinq%20ans%20de%20plus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20quinze%20ans%20de%20plus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20six%20ans%20de%20plus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20trente%20ans%20de%20plus%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20huit%20ans%20de%20plus%3B%2Cc0) » sont courantes ; je pense donc qu'une alternative à la solution ci-dessus, qui préserve « de », serait comme suit ;

- Ma sœur a sept ans de moins que moi.

En fin de compte, je n'appellerais pas cette dernière solution vraiment plus naturelle, mais elle est certainement plus simple, plus habituelle ; il me semble cependant que la forme qui emploie « agée » n'est quand même pas gauche.

Comment: A vrai dire, et sans remettre en cause l'exactitude de votre réponse, je trouve "Ma soeur est 7 ans moins agée que moi" bien plus naturel. En voulant se présenter sous un meilleur jour on peut aussi remplacer "moins agée" par "plus jeune".

Comment: @LaurentS. So my sentence is more natural, but I shouldn't use "de"?